# Obtaining image dimensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I am using carrierwave to upload images and I need to obtain the image dimensions and store them when uploaded.

CarrierWave has a solution:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  process :store_dimensions

  private

  def store_dimensions
    if file && model
      img = ::Magick::Image::read(file.file).first
      model.width = img.columns
      model.height = img.rows
    end
  end
end
```

Whilst I can see how this would store the dimensions in db fields called height & width for a single image I am usiing a multiple file uploader.
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

How can I store these image dimensions when uploading multiple files?

**Edit1**

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]
  process :get_geometry

  def geometry
    @geometry
  end

  def get_geometry
    if (@file)
      @geometry = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(@file.file)[:dimensions]
    end
  end    

end


2.4.1 :001 > Post.last.attachments.first.geometry
  Post Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.4.1 :002 > Post.last.attachments.first.get_geometry
  Post Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => [400, 200]
```

**Edit2**

If I use the carrierwave suggestion below which stores these vals in db fields then it works for a single image however when I am uploading multiple images each subsequent image overwrites the values so I may have three images but only one val for height and width stored.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :store_dimensions

  private

  def store_dimensions
    if file && model
      model.width, model.height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Coudnt you something like this dependning on the name of the model?

```
version :post do
  process :resize_to_fit => [200, nil]
  process :get_geometry

  def geometry
    @geometry
  end
end

def get_geometry
  if (@file)
    img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
    @geometry = [ img.columns, img.rows ]
  end
end
```

And then you could in a after save callback read out the geometry for the image and save it in custom db rows in your model.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Where is @geometry stored so I can access the values within ?

Comment: Not accessible through post.geometry ?

Comment: Sorry, I currently do not have a running app with carrierwave to test it by myself

Comment: Does carrierwave provide an "after_process" callback for the model that you can access the get_geometry method and save the value in a db column. (You have to create the db column first. e.g. an serialized attribute or width and height as separate columns)

Comment: Or try it maybe in a after_save callback -> when width, height not set, then grab the info from self.get_geometry?